# How to call intent from AlertDialog in Animatedview ?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have game,in after game is over I use AlertDialog with EditText and Button to enter the name and finally I have to save the current score and player name into database when I click on button,its fine I can able to save score and name. My requirement is that I want to change to the intent to game home page(HomeActivity) when I click on same button.

My code is:

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{
String name;
static int count=0;
private Context mContext;
int x = 130;
int y = 450;
private float a,b;
private int xVelocity = 20;
private int yVelocity = 20;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 25;
BitmapDrawable ball;
boolean touching;
boolean dm_touched = false;
float move=3;
int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;
boolean paused;
private Paint line, ball1, background;
static int click=0;
private static final int TEXT_ID = 0;
DBCeation dbCeation;
public AnimatedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context; 
    h = new Handler();
} 

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Log.e("game","run called");
        if(touching = true)
        invalidate(); 
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        //x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = c.getHeight()/2;


    } else {
        //Log.d("s",""+xVelocity);
        Log.d("s",""+yVelocity);
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||y <0) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
   //Log.e("sarat",""+touching);

  if(click>=2){
  if(bm_h+y>630){

       final EditText input=new EditText(mContext);
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"game over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      builder.setTitle("Game Is Over");
        builder.setMessage("Enter your Name");
         // Use an EditText view to get user input.
         input.setId(TEXT_ID);
         builder.setView(input);
         builder.setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                name=input.getText().toString();
                Log.d("name",""+name);
                int score=MainActivity.score;
                dbCeation=new DBCeation(mContext);
                dbCeation.insertValues(name, score);
 //this code is not working and gives compile time error
                Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
      builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


      builder.show();
      x=150;
      y=200;
      xVelocity=0;
      yVelocity=0;

  }}
    if(touching){
         // Log.e("game","iftouch called called");
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
      }
  }
```

Comment: use `mContext.startActivity(intent);` which will get a context to start the activity

Comment: If it is working accept the answer which suits your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would help you

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

else try with

```
mContext.getApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `finish()` will end the activity that you created so I am removing it

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mContext` you already set Activity Context in the `mContext`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: unable to write startActivity(intent); it gives compile time error

Comment: The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: @bharat I have edited my answer you need to call startActvity with mContext.

Comment: @bharat now it's Working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have start your Activity from AlertDialog in your code start your Activity with that Context. So use this.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
 mContext.startActivity(intent);
```